# Ambari - Trouble Checking Status for Custom Application

Tags: python, hadoop, ambari

I've been playing around with creating a custom application inside of our Ambari installation. After a little bit of toying, I've successfully got this configured to do the installation and startup actions with the appropriate log creation\output and pid creation. The piece that I'm struggling with now is having Ambari maintain the status of this newly installed application. After following some of the instructions here : http://mozartanalytics.com/how-to-create-a-software-stack-for-ambari/ (specifically the Component Status section), I've been able to make some progress -- however it's not exactly what I want.

When including the following in master.py, Ambari will see the service as momentarily active after initial startup, but then the application will appear as red (offline). It marks it as offline, even though when I check the server, I see the appropriate process running.

```
def status(self, env):
    import params
    print 'Checking status of pid file'
    check=format("{params.pid}/Application.pid")
    check_process_status(check)
```

However, when I modify it to look like the following, Ambari has no problem tracking the status and monitors it appropriately

```
def status(self, env):
    import params
    print 'Checking status of pid file'
    dummy_master_pid_file = "/var/run/Application/Application.pid"
    check_process_status(dummy_master_pid_file)
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is there something that I'm missing in regards to creating this custom application inside of Ambari? Any help or pointing in the right direction will be appreciated.

FYI. This is Ambari 2.1 running on Centos 6.7

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have solved a similar problem. And the solution is to put a string "{"securityState": "UNKNOWN"}" into the file -  /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/structured-out-status.json. 
  The way to find this solution is by watching ambari-agent log :  PythonExecutor.py:149 - {'msg': 'Unable to read structured output from /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/structured-out-status.json'}. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is your parameter problem.

```
  def status(self, env):
        import params
        print 'Checking status of pid file'
        pid_path = params.pid
        check=format("{pid_path}/Application.pid")
        check_process_status(check)
```